# RAD WebSphere NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, noclassdeffounderror, rad

My projects look like this

```
EAR_proj
  lib/
    3rd party jars

EJB_proj

Web_proj (a web service with WSDL)

Common_proj1
Common_proj2
```

EAR_proj has Deployment Assembly contains all other projects

All projects have "EAR library" in their classpath for the 3rd party libraries.

The Web_proj has Deployment Assembly contains Common_proj1 and Common_proj2 (in its MANIFEST.MF)

However when I deploy the Web_project to the server (within RAD), I kept getting NoClassDefFoundError for 1 class that resides within Common_proj1.

Looking at WebSphere ffdc error file, it says

```
FFDC Exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException SourceId:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.utils.Axis2Utils.getApplicationClassPath ProbeId:874
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Common_proj1\bin (Access is denied.)
```

The other ffdc file indicate Common_proj1/bin is on the classpath of some ClassLoader...I'm not sure why it doesn't just treat Common_proj1 as a jar file. Is it because this happen within the IDE?

The server Classloader policy is set to "Single" and "Classes loaded with parent class loader first" policy

Answer (score 0):

Turn out this is a RAD problem after upgrading to a newer JDK.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21667356

Adding the attribute wsldLocation in the web service implementation class solves the problem.